# Export to HTML using Jasper Report or Dynamic Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

How can we export HTML to a specific page. Suppose I want to display report in a page called 'viewreport.jsp' . How do I specify the page to which the export should be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate report and put it as pdf in an iframe or use target="_blank" and open document.